# Avoiding source-level "jumping around" in gdb

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb

With C++ code built for debugging with g++ (i.e. options "-O0 -ggdb") and using the newest gcc (5.1.0) and gdb (7.9) the display of source code in gdb is still painfully non-linear when using the "next" command. As an example this function call might be expected to step through with a single "next":

```
7757|   SDValue NewRoot = TLI->LowerFormalArguments(
7758|      DAG.getRoot(), F.getCallingConv(), F.isVarArg(), Ins, dl, DAG, InVals);
```

however it takes four, with the displayed execution line being first 7757, then 7758, then again 7757, then again 7758. If the function call is condensed to a single line then just one "next" is needed. If the call is absurdly inflated then seven "next"s are needed (shown as the '#' annotations)

```
       7757|   SDValue
       7758| NewRoot
       7759| =
  #1,6 7760| TLI
       7761| ->
       7762| LowerFormalArguments(
    #5 7763|       DAG.getRoot(),
       7764| F.getCallingConv(),
    #3 7765| F.isVarArg(),
       7766| Ins,
       7767| dl,
       7768| DAG,
       7769| InVals
#2,4,7 7770| );
```

So it's related to but not as simple as "each function call on a distinct line is a stepping point". This gets especially confusing with breakpoints in recursive functions, where I find myself checking the callstack to see whether it's really a new invocation or just a phony backwards step.

Since reflowing all of the LLVM source to contain function calls in a single line isn't really a viable option, is there some gcc/gdb option for controlling this behaviour?

EDIT: now checked with clang 3.5 and lldb 3.5: when built with clang only three "next"s occur. And gdb and lldb see the same "next" behaviour in either case (i.e. 4 with gcc, 3 with clang)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of behavior from the debugger is a "GIGO" situation -- that is, normally gdb is just doing whatever the debug info tells it to do.  That is, when there is odd behavior, it is generally due to decisions made by the compiler.  It may be a bug, and probably worth a bug report, but I also wouldn't be surprised if it is intended to work this way for some reason.

You can investigate these kinds of problems by using `readelf` or `objdump` to examine the line table.

Comment: From `readelf --debug-dump` it's apparent that clang emits far more "advance Address by X and Line by Y" DWARF opcodes than gcc does for the same code blocks, but with both compilers it's unpredictable when this will happen (e.g. whether an automatic object's destructor will get a separate "advance" at the end of a scope)

Comment: But having wandered (ignorantly) around in DWARF-land it seems obvious that there's no way the debugger could elide these intermediate advances, i.e. there doesn't seem to be anything specific to a statement terminator that a "next-statement" command could exploit. So the compiler would to change the granularity of the advance opcodes, and I guess neither gcc nor clang currently has an exposed control for this